# How can I install .Net 3.5 on Windows 10?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-10, localdb

I need to install .Net 3.5 so I can use SQL Server Express/Local Db in Visual Studio.

I have trawled the internet looking for answers and nothing works.

It got stuck on this all night, this is enabling .Net 3.5 from the Control Panel.

[image: http://imgur.com/YZcIJeX]

I even redownloaded Windows 10 and run this DISM command

```
DISM  /Online  /Enable-Feature  /FeatureName:NetFx3  /All  /LimitAccess  /Source:c:\sources\sxs
```

but it still hangs and won't do anything.

[image: http://imgur.com/C0OS3Lc]

If anyone could help me out that would be super helpful

Comment: did you try the install from the disk?

Comment: Couldn't you just re-target your project to use a newer version of .NET?

Comment: I would try it using the media: http://www.askvg.com/how-to-install-microsoft-net-framework-3-5-offline-in-windows-8-without-internet-connection/

Comment: austinwernli I'm doing it from a USB, no disks available.
@BinarySpark I don't really know how, I'm following the ASP.NET tutorials and they use localdb.

Comment: Why "c:\sources\sxs"? All other success stories download the ISO, mount as drive D and use "d:\sources\sxs".

Comment: @LexLi I've got it on a USB stick. Have trued e:\sources\sxs as well. No luck

Comment: Install all the existing updates. Restart the computer..

Comment: have you ever got .net 3.5 installed?

Answer (score 6):

.NET 3.5 cant be install by internet. you have to use your installation DVD or ISO downloaded from Microsoft website. 
use this command to install

`DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /Source:d:\sources\sxs /All /LimitAccess`

d: should be the

- ISO mapped drive if you use ISO file
- DVD drive if you use installation DVD

Few important points.

- If you use ISO file, There can be errors if you try to use a ISO from a network location.
- If you download ISO from Microsoft web site careful about 32 bit and 64 bit.
- Run command prompt as Administrator to run this command
- If your command prompt hang without any response, probably it means Some windows updates  installation is in progress. So restart the computer and try again.
- Go to "Turn Windows feature on or off" window.If you installed properly, you can see .NET framework 3.5 is installed.

Here is the step by step guide I have written. http://codeketchup.blogspot.sg/2015/11/how-to-install-net-framework-35-on.html

Comment: With this answer I have turned on the .NET 3.5 using DISM command since MS-DOS Console of Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to MSDN subscription, download the [`Windows 10 Features on Demand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/subscriptions/securedownloads/?#searchTerm=Windows%2010%20Features%20on%20Demand&ProductFamilyId=0&Languages=en&PageSize=10&PageIndex=0&FileId=0) ISO, mount it and run this command:

```
DISM.EXE /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:NetFx3~~~~ /Source:D:\
```

(where D: is the mounted ISO)

If this fails, run this command to add the files back to your Windows

```
DISM.EXE /Online /Add-Package /PackagePath:D:\Microsoft-Windows-NetFx3-OnDemand-Package.cab
```

and now go to the UI to enable the feature.

Comment: This worked for me, it was great for an Azure VM that refused to install .NET 3.5

Comment: Link note: Apparently, the `Win 10 Features on Demand` is currently found under https://my.visualstudio.com/downloads (then type it in the search box) (Direct Link: https://download.my.visualstudio.com/db/en_windows_10_features_on_demand_x64_dvd_6846440_.iso)

Comment: @MartinBa Microsoft has changed this a lot. the Microsoft-Windows-NetFx3-OnDemand-Package.cab is not also part of the normal Win10 ISO under sources\sxs ("DRIVE:\sources\sxs\microsoft-windows-netfx3-ondemand-package.cab")

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have your Windows installation media at hand or want it easier:

These are the methods without the commandline DISM command, which work interactively- for the first two you need current internet access:

1. Normally it is enough to **start an application** requiring .NET 3.5 and Windows will bring up a dialog for installation over internet.
2. Type "windows feature" in the magnifier (search) line besides the start button and switch to

   > Turn Windows features on or off
   >       Control panel

   Then you find the known dialog from previous versions to turn .NET 3.5 features on, etc. (At least I was unable to find it from new settings dialog without search.)
3. If you **updated Windows 10**, and you had .NET 3.5 activated before on Win 7 or 8.x, then you have to do nothing, it is also activated in Windows 10.
4. Here is the real **offline "emergency" installer**:
   http://www.smart-arab.com/2013/12/install-net-on-windows-8-1-and-windows-10-offline/
   Of course this is not the official way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to add remove programs and then add features to windows, then select it from here. This will install .net 3.5 and 2.0

edit 1

Please open a command prompt (cmd.exe) as admin and run the following command to install .Net 3.5:

```
DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /Source:d:\sources\sxs /All /LimitAccess
```

(replace D: with your mounted Win10 ISO)

In some environment, DISM fails to fetch the file (Proxy, network policies). The DISM command takes the files from the DVD and you're fine

Comment: I've tried this. I left it all night and its stuck on this http://imgur.com/YZcIJeX

Comment: here are screenshots of the above.
http://imgur.com/VqNIKeV here is USB stick.
And it hangs here http://imgur.com/RCjNEtS. I've been trying this way as well all morning because I saw it in another forum

Comment: No it just hangs like that

Comment: @AlexHarley ive had a number of issues with windows 10, this one isnt one of them (fortunately). I'll continue looking for alternative methods

Comment: Thanks for you help. I'm going to look for alternatives. I just want to code

Comment: @AlexHarley i have just re-edited the answer, i know that feeling about just wanting to code... this is why im dropping back down to Windows 8.1 tomorrow.. Win10 with VS2015 sucks for me

Comment: scratch that, the edit wont work, just took it back out

Comment: everywhere Im looking right now says the same things `DISM  /Online  /Enable-Feature  /FeatureName:NetFx3  /All  /LimitAccess  /Source:x:\sources\sxs` have you got any other pending updates?

Comment: No nothing further. I'm just trying to connect to localdb from VS

Comment: what did you need to do?

Comment: The DB part I mean. Still don't know why it was hanging so much on everything. But I connected to the local db which was my main issue since yesterday. Thanks so much for taking the time to help me

Comment: I changed the connection string in the web.config file. As well as creating a localdb instance from the command line. Whew. So stoked its working

Answer (score 0):

[image] 1. Open CMD as an administrate

Command: Dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /All /Source:D:\sources\sxs /LimitAccess

**here D=partition name Mout**

Open ISO file of **windows 10** and type D where Partition.

Finally Open Windows Features and then you will see Net Framework 3.5 has been install and enable.

Answer (score 0):

A Windows Update group policy can disable the update. If this is the case:

- Go into RegEdit and navigate to the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU folder.
- Double-click on UseWUServer and change the value to 0.
- Try to install .NET 3.5 from the Turn Windows Features on and off dialog or through the .NET 3.5 installer (dotnetfx35.exe) provided by Microsoft.